# Passing data recursively with threads

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, recursion

I am trying to pass values recursively with threading.

In my example, I am creating a thread and i pass it some data, and this thread creates another thread recursively, which also passes it some data.

The output is the following:

```
Thread 1: value = 8
Thread 2: value = 12318230
```

Why am I not getting the value 4 for the second thread even though I assigned it the value 4?

From my understanding (please correct me if I am wrong), each thread has its own stack. When I pass the value 4 to Thread 2 (the thread created by the first thread), the variable is in memory until the thread ends. Since I have a call to pthread_join, I wait until the child thread ends until I resume. I am uncertain why the value of Thread 2 is some random number.

```
int count = 0

typedef struct
{
  int value;
} ThreadInfo;

void* ChildWork(void* a) {

  pthread_t threadid;

  count++;
  if(count > 2)
  pthread_exit(0);

  ThreadInfo* info = (ThreadInfo*)a; 
  printf("value = %d\n", info->value);

  ThreadInfo* child = new ThreadInfo; 
  child->value = 4;
  pthread_create(&threadid, NULL, ChildWork, (void*)&child);
  pthread_join(threadid, NULL);

  pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  pthread_t threadid;
  ThreadInfo info;
  info.value = 8;

  pthread_create(&threadid, NULL, ChildWork, (void*)&info);
  pthread_join(threadid, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Race conditions on accessing `count` are likely to appear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ThreadInfo* child = new ThreadInfo; 
child->value = 4;
pthread_create(&threadid, NULL, ChildWork, (void*)&child);
```

&child is a `ThreadInfo**` but the child thread casts it to a `ThreadInfo*` and reads garbage. Change `(void*)&child` to just `child`.